# Declaring HTML constants (not cyphers)

Tags: javascript, html, constants, html-entities

As part of what I'll be first to admit is a lame excuse for a sci-fi novel I'm writing as an HTML application (offline, of course), I had thought of creating a *conlang* for some of my characters. As part of developing a lexicon for the conlang, I thought it would be useful to define <kbd><!ENTITY></kbd> codes to create halfway-mnemonic text constants [say

```
<!--    embellish as needed    embellish as needed    embellish as needed    -->
<!DOCTYPE html [
  <!ENTITY K1_hamza  "&#x2019;"> <!-- cosmetic cc hrairoo/5-ling consonant -->
  <!ENTITY K1_Ltr3   "&#x0417;"> <!-- cosmetic uc hrairoo/5-ling vowel
                                                 [Cyrillic 'Ze'] -->
  <!ENTITY K1_ltr3   "&#x0437;"> <!-- cosmetic lc hrairoo/5-ling vowel
                                                 [Cyrillic 'ze'] -->
  <!ENTITY K1_langname           "(-; If I tell you, I'll have to kill you ;-)">
]>
```

for displays of ‹’›, ‹З›, ‹з› and the conlang's name respectively—note also the Magyar prefixes] defined within a *specific* coding area, allowing me to change the entity displays all at once through the entire document instead of requiring me to hunt down and replace frequently-used *explicit* constants at every other turn (I don't have to tell you how much of a pain in the lower realms *that* can be).

However, the literature on declaring <kbd><!ENTITY>s</kbd> is a bit confusing. Some sources claim to present strategies, but I have yet to find one that will work in my code. Other sources say that <kbd><!ENTITY>s</kbd> may be added to some dialects of HTML but not to others (even dialects which "present" as being backward-compatible with "<kbd><!ENTITY></kbd>-accepting" dialects—HTML5 [which I think my system is using] is *one* problematic example). If worse comes to worse, I could probably rig something up in JavaScript, but an HTML-based solution would probably be more device-independent.

Any help you can provide in untangling the truth in this matter will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to HTML5, HTML was an application of SGML ([Standard Generalized Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) which allows the definition of entities of form <!ENTITY .... > which you are seeking to use.

HTML5 is no longer an SGML application and uses a simple [document type declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype) of

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Previous versions of HTML were SGML based and used a DOCTYPE declaration containing a reference to a [Document Type Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) or "dtd" file which could contain [SGML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML_entity#SGML_document_entity) definitions.

However, whether HTML4 browsers downloaded "dtd" files and parsed them is another question - mostly they seem to have checked to see which version of HTML was declared and whether the DTD was "strict" or "transitional" with everything else rendered in "quirks mode".

Current character entities for HTML5 are defined [in the HTML5 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) and also available from the W3C [as a chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), leading me to conclude that custom SGML entities are not going to work under HTML5,  even if they at some time, in some browser, with some previous version of HTML, worked in the past.

Defining [custom elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) in HTML in combination with CSS has possibilities but I don't know how well they would match your requirements. Some of the HTML templating frameworks might also provide a solution.

Comment: I could think of a few computer programming instructors who'd give HTML5 a big fat juicy F on self-documentation